# Application Loader - build pushed on wrong app builds

Tags: ios, app-store, application-loader

i explain my problem.

We are two applications with the same name "MyApp" currently created on the itunes connect dashboard.

We did able to create two application with the same name using a different language localization (one in english and the other in native italian). Over this, applications are distributed to different countries (so the swiss - aka ch - version won't be visible to the italian - aka it - users).

**Problem Context**

The problem is related to the application upload: i'm using the Application Loader software to upload the respective ipa (myapp.1.0.9.prod.it.ipa and myapp.1.0.9.prod.it.ipa) to their remote application project dashboards.

**What's wrong?**

When i'm publishing the app for ch (myapp.1.0.9.prod.ch.ipa) and the process end correctly, **if i open the TestFlight tab for the ch app, i'm not able to see my build** but **instead, it's result available for the it version.**

**How we distinguish apps in the project**

To distinguish rightly the application, we performing a general renaming of the package name inside all project files to aim this situation:
myapp.1.0.9.prod.ch.ipa with package name "com.myapp.domain.ch"
myapp.1.0.9.prod.it.ipa with package name "com.myapp.domain" (considered as default)

**Goals**

Publish current ipad downloaded to its app project.

**Limits**

Please don't provide me solution that include itunes with the Archive menu, we cannot do it manually due to a builder dependencies that will be very pedantic without builder's feature.

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Simon

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you are changing the package name. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that but you have to be sure you are setting the correct **Bundle Identifier**, or `CFBundleIdentifier` in your Info.plist to make your ipa upload to the correct iTunes Connect application.

Can you take a peek inside your generated `.ipa` and make sure you have the Bundle Identifier set as you expect?

Comment: You are a genius!!! :) 

The problem is that building with phonegap build a cordova project, and without specify the ios-CFBundleIdentifier, i don't know why phonegap put inside the generated info.plist file the identifier of the standard release (that for IT). 

I will try know to specify it inside my config.xml and i will let you know.

Anyway, thanks for your answer (Y)

Comment: Ok so just a recap. The problem was related to the bundle identifier that i discover that phonegap builder is not bind correctly with id specified in the config.xml if the key provided are from another id. So, to solve my problem at the end i created other two set of certificates (one for distribution and one for development - both provided with provisioning, etc). At the end of the build, the file id reported inside file **info.plist** was correct. 

Thanks man